# how to edit any tcp packets alive on the fly then re send it?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, packets

```
Client Application     ====>               Server Application
                   Natural TCP Packets
Local Machine          ====>               Remote Machine 




Client Application     ====> INTERCEPTOR PACKETS   ===>        Server Application
                          Edited TCP Packets
Local Machine          ====> INTERCEPTOR PACKETS   ===>            Remote Machine
```

I Heard about Layered Service Provider but i do not know any point to start

i mean editing any type of packets (http/https/rtmp/smtp/....)

or is there any tool to do this ?
or any C# using pcap library ?
or using TcpListener class ?

this is my project of memory studies any help would be very appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is many tools for this but unfortunately all in `unix operation system`

1- Hex2Inject     http://hexinject.sourceforge.net/

2 - ProxyShark http://code.google.com/p/proxyshark/

3-  Scapy  [www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)

4 - mallory https://github.com/intrepidusgroup/mallory

5- netsed http://silicone.homelinux.org/projects/netsed/

all these tool are capable to `modify` (edit) any `packet` of any `protocol` on the `fly` then `re send` it `on the wire` and this is `MAN IN THE MIDDLE`

**Note :**  for `http/https/ws` fiddler should be the best debugging tool for http/https/ws(web socket) traffic http://fiddler2.com

Comment: hi @K3rnel31 is there anyway to install this softwares to windows? I'm sorry for my noob question

Comment: @ShaunZyrille for http/ssl there is fiddler , but for other protocols there is not

Comment: Ok @K3rnel31 thanks for your reply! Do you know something about RTMP protocol? Can these tools modify an image file before sending it through RTMP connection?

Comment: @ShaunZyrille they can ,  but  it is hard to it via bytes , you will not be ablee to debug  thee mesage of RTMP aannd edit it  , you will  see only bytes includingg headers and body  , so you  will need to edit only the body part and  only with  bytes or Hex